# Flutter Local notifications - notification click is not working while the app in background

Tags: flutter

When application killed then notification click not working account to onSelectNotification and also big picture image notification not working when app in background.

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
onSelectNotification: (action) {})
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you are asking. Can you explain what you *want* to happen? Post the code for this. And then explain what happens *instead*, including any error messages you may get?

Comment: I need to open specific page when click on notification. when app open(Foreground) then its working fine but when app in background then click action not working.

@nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

Handle background messages by registering a onBackgroundMessage handler. When messages are received, an isolate is spawned (Android only, iOS/macOS does not require a separate isolate) allowing you to handle messages even when your application is not running. try this:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

follow full documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

Comment: While this would probably work, it assumes the OP is using FireBase, which they did not mention.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "in the background" with mobile devices. Mobile devices run *one* foreground app. When you "put it in the background" it is closed and a screenshot is kept to make you think it's "in the background". It's not. It's closed.

So it does not work when it's closed. That's normal. Because the app isn't running, it cannot execute code.

The app has first to be started again. To find out, whether your app was started by tapping a notification, you can use this line in your start up code:

```
final NotificationAppLaunchDetails notificationAppLaunchDetails =
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
```

[Source: Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#getting-details-on-if-the-app-was-launched-via-a-notification-created-by-this-plugin)

This way you can find out if your app was started from your notification and then act accordingly (for example by navigating to a different route depending on those details).